# d3 ／ In rangePoints method, when you set the padding, the calculation formula of the value?

Tags: d3.js

```
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal() .domain(['a', 'b', 'c']) .rangePoints([0, 900],10);
xScale1('a'); //375
```

How it was calculated doing 375?

Comment: Did you check [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal_rangePoints)?

Comment: Quick look at the function in d3 code [rangePoints](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/3abb00113662463e5c19eb87cd33f6d0ddc23bc0/d3.js#L7741)

Comment: What is `xScale1`? Is that just a typo or are you indeed referring to two different scales?